# Heroku Hobby Plan pricing calculation for 100 applications

Tags: heroku

I am very confused with the heroku hobby plan which states $7/dynos/month. Say if I have deployed 100 applications on my hobby plan how much will it cost me to host them? will it cost me as follows:
100 applications * $7 = $700/month?

Comment: This is not really a programming question, so it's off-topic here. Just note that Heroku doesn't bill per _app_, it bills per _dyno_. Those are different things. You can also be billed for the use of add-ons.

Comment: Yes 1 app can have more than one dynos but can we have more than one app on one dynos? If not then the minimum charge per month for 100 apps is $700 on hobby?

Comment: No, you cannot run multiple apps on one dyno.

Comment: So basically if i am to deploy 2 apps on heroku hobby, maximum will be $14 per month?

Comment: Well Hobby dynos don't exist anymore. [You can choose between Eco for $5 a month or Basic for $7 a month](https://www.heroku.com/dynos). then it goes up from there.

Comment: So let me put the question like this. Can I host more than one application on basic plan for $7 maximum per month?

Comment: Please see my second comment: "No, you cannot run multiple apps on one dyno". So unless you want to run each app only part-time, e.g. 12 hours per day, it would appear not.